# “Best response” questions and answers from database analysis

Tags: discussion, answers

I’ve noticed that when there’s a question about “the best response” to some move in an opening, answerers will often cite a database of master-level games and respond with the top scoring responses in the database. While I don’t have a problem with that, these answers will often *only* contain that information with no explanation or analysis. This doesn’t seem like a very helpful way to answer.

Is there any policy for what an answer to these “best response questions” should contain? Or is it just something that gets sorted by voting?

Answer (score 3):

There's no policy at the moment, and IMHO there shouldn't be one. You can always downvote the answer if you think it *is not useful*:

[image]

or, if you *do* think it's useful, upvote it. Personally, I always try to add an explanation about the quality/popularity of certain moves, but sometimes it's hard to tell why a move is good/popular.

Comment: @Dennis Dear Dennis, please consider accepting if you've found this answer satisfactory. Thank you